# Calling main inside the code

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Can we call `main()` function inside any other function? I tried but did not come up with it.

If we can't call it then why?

Why `main()` is not like ordinary methods?

Comment: `main()` **is** like any other ordinary method. What is your problem? What is the error you get? Where is your code?

Comment: code is too much long it 1300+ lines,

Comment: Give a Short-simple-concise-workable code... Or atleast give the complete error message or just the lines that are calling the `main` method

Answer (score 2):

Yes why not try something like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

If you run:

```
java NewMain
```

the output is:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why main() is not like ordinary methods

Not like ordinary methods in what sense? It *is* like any other method. I'll try to explain why `main` looks like this, maybe it'll help you to understand what's going on.

It's `void` because when it finishes, it doesn't mean that the program finished. If it spawns a *new thread* it might be that these threads are still running.

It's `public` because it's called by the JVM, which is outside the scope of the project.

And of course it has to be `static` because when the JVM calls it, there's no object existing for the class being called.

Nothing special about it when you understand it, so yes.. it can be called like any other `static` method.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, main() is like nay other method in that area.

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("a's main()");
        B.main(new String[0]);
    }
}

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("B's main()");

    }

}
```

Running A's main() will produce:

```
a's main()
B's main()
```

Answer (score 0):

All the actions that you do one other methods can also be done on the main method

The only difference between main method and other methods is that the main method servers as the starting point for running a class

The java command launches a Java application. It does this by starting a Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and invoking that class's main method.

Except for this reason, there is nothing else.